# There has been an error processing your request

Tags: php, magento2, stack-trace

I am very new to magento and i was just install magento in Linux server with cpanel and i got error.

[image]
and every time when i refresh page i got new error

i find files under your documentroot/var/report
[image]

Comment: Open that file and see what it says

Answer (score 0):

To know the exact error you have to check the logs file

you can check that in the below folder.

```
magento_root_folder/var/log
magento_root_folder/var/report
```

Also in case if you directly want to know the reason of the error you can enable the developer option which helps you to solve this error.

run below command from the ssh to change to developer mode.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

this will turn developer mode on.

you can also follow additional steps to get more details.

edit .htaccess file or root change from

```
#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
```

To

```
   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
```

**remove # symbol**

in the below file

```
magento_root_folder/app/bootstrap.php
```

add error reporting flag to show actual error.

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```